# Google App Engine Devserver + dispatch.yaml (gcloud)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dispatcher, dev-appserver

I am trying to start my app using the new cloud SDK preview (gcloud preview app run DIRNAME) and the response is:

```
INFO: Starting API server at: http://localhost:51695
INFO: Starting module "api" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO: Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8081
INFO: Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

The dispatcher is not running and I can't get a dispatcher service URL as described 
[here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing#dispatch_files).

The dispatcher is fully function on production, but I just can't get it started via dev server.

How can i make Google Cloud SDK recognize dispatch.yaml?

The dispatch.yaml looks like this:

```
application: my-super-secret-app-id
dispatch:
- url: "*/"
  module: default

- url: "*/_*"
  module: api
```

The goal is to server all "regular" requests from the default module, and request begins with underscore to the "api" module.

Comment: What does your dispatch.yaml file look like?

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Removing Google Cloud SDK completely and re-installing it's latest version solved the problem.